# Possible number of subsets that must intersect of $\{1,2,3,...100\}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

$S$ be a collection  of  subsets  of  $\{1,2,3.....100\}$  such that the intersection of  any two sets in $S$ is non-empty . What is the maximum possible cardinality $|S|$ of $S?$

$A.100$

$B.2^{100}$

$C.2^{99}$

$D.2^{98}$

Now  one thing I  can  tell  is  that  , *if all the subsets  have cardinality $51$ or more then  the  property  easily  holds. So  can I  say $$\sum_{k=51}^{100} \binom{100}{k}$$  is  a possible  answer  although  it is not equal to any  of the ones given in the options.

So, this is not the proper method. Then I thought there is another thing : whatever  the cardinality , the subsets can be chosen in such a way that that they always intersect , with restrictions applying.

So, how  do  I  approach  the  problem ,please show  me a proper way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have all the subsets share one element, making $2^{99}$.

Suppose we have more that work. Then, we can remove subsets, until we have $2^{99}+1$ that work.

Define the $2^{99}$ pigeonholes by pairing subsets and their complement. Here, I demonstrate when we replace $100$ with $3$.

- $\{1, 2, 3\}, \{\}$
- $\{1, 2\}, \{3\}$
- $\{1, 3\}, \{2\}$
- $\{1\}, \{2,3\}$

Then by Pigeonhole Principle, since we have $2^{99}$ pigeonholes and $2^{99}+1$ pigeons, we have $2$ pigeons in a pigeonhole, so we have $2$ subsets, one the complement of the other. They do not intersect. Contradiction.

Comment: I could not understand the pigeonholes logic .

Comment: I understand  know. Thanks